# Insert string into sorted array of strings with binary search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have the following alphabetically sorted array of strings:

```
let collection = ["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"];
```

I want to insert the string `"CQW"` inside the collection whilst preserving the sorted order **but without** having to sort the whole array all over again.

So I would like to have `["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "CQW", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"];` after the insertion completed in `O(log n)` time.

I figured it would be a good idea to calculate the index at which I need to insert the element using binary search.

I have found the following code for binary search which retrieves the index of a string if it is existent inside a collection:

```js
function binarySearch(items, value) {
  let startIndex = 0;
  let stopIndex = items.length - 1;
  let middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex) / 2);

  while (items[middle] != value && startIndex < stopIndex) {

    //adjust search area
    if (value < items[middle]) {
      stopIndex = middle - 1;
    } else if (value > items[middle]) {
      startIndex = middle + 1;
    }

    //recalculate middle
    middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex) / 2);
  }

  // Return -1 if element is not in collection
  return (items[middle] != value) ? -1 : middle;
}

let collection = ["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"];

console.log(binarySearch(collection, "CQW"));
```

However, I have been struggling with modifying it so that it returns the precise index at which the string needs to be inserted. How can this be modified so that it works? Is binary search the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're inserting into an array you are always going to have a worst case of `O(n)` in just moving values around "after" the insertion (+ an additional `n` or `log n` for finding the place to insert the value at). So i would either just append the value at one end of the array and then sort it with insertion sort (since insertion sort is actually one of the faster algorithms for almost-sorted input data).

```js
const insertionSort = (inputArr) => {
    const length = inputArr.length;
    for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        const key = inputArr[i];
        let j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && inputArr[j] > key) {
            inputArr[j + 1] = inputArr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        inputArr[j + 1] = key;
    }
    return inputArr;
};

let collection = ["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"];

collection.push("CQW");
console.log(insertionSort(collection));
```

Or, if you tend to end up with HUGE arrays and need `O(n)` worst case complexity for insertion; then i would move to an always sorted doubly-linked list instead.

```js
const linkedList = (value, next) => ({prev: null, value, next});
const insert = (node, value) => {
  if (node === null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (node.value < value) {
    return insert(node.next, value);
  }
  const newNode = linkedList(value, node);
  newNode.prev = node.prev;
  newNode.prev.next = newNode;
  node.prev = newNode;
  return true;
} 
const arrayToList = (arr) => arr.reverse().reduce((next, el) => {
  const list = linkedList(el, next);
  if (next) {
    next.prev = list;
  }
  return list;
}, null);
const printList = (list) => {
  const arr = [];
  let node = list;
  while (node) {
    arr.push(node.value);
    node = node.next;
  }
  console.log(arr);
};


const collection = ["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"];
const list = arrayToList(collection);
insert(list, "CQW");

printList(list);


// Some function that arent't used in the example
// but are very usefull if you decided to use this solution
const get = (list, index) => {
  let node = list;
  for (let i = 0; node; i++) {
    if (i === index) {
      return node.value;
    }
    node = node.next;
  }
  return null;
}
const set = (list, index, value) => {
  let node = list;
  for (let i = 0; node; i++) {
    if (i === index) {
      node.value = value;
      return true;
    }
    node = node.next;
  }
  return false;
}
const remove = (list, value) => {
  if (node === null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (node.value === value) {
    node.prev.next = node.next;
    node.next.prev = node.prev;
    return true;
  }
  return remove(node.next, value);
}
const getIndex = (list, value) => {
  let node = list;
  for (let i = 0; node; i++) {
    if (node.value === value) {
      return i;
    }
    node = node.next;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: The best solution and explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `middle` value  should tell you where to put it. Modify the function's return value so it tells you if it's already in the collection as well

```js
function binarySearch(items, value) {
  console.log('Searching for '+value)
  let startIndex = 0;
  let stopIndex = items.length - 1;
  let middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex) / 2);

  while (items[middle] != value && startIndex < stopIndex) {

    //adjust search area
    if (value < items[middle]) {
      stopIndex = middle - 1;
    } else if (value > items[middle]) {
      startIndex = middle + 1;
    }

    //recalculate middle
    middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex) / 2);
  }

  // Return -1 if element is not in collection
  // return (items[middle] != value) ? -1 : middle;
  return {
      found: items[middle] == value,
      middle: middle
  }
}

let collection = ["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"];
let item = "CQW"
result= binarySearch(collection, item);
console.log(result)
if(!result.found){
    console.log('Adding '+item+' at index '+result.middle)
    collection.splice(result.middle, 0, item);
}
console.log(collection)
```

Output

```
Searching for CQW
{found: false, middle: 3}
Adding CQW at index 3
["ABC", "BCD", "CAB", "CQW", "FGH", "JKL", "ZKL"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately both previous answers are not very... correct, but I don't have enough reputation to make comments, so I'm putting everything here in my answer.

**tl:dr The best solution in practice is the simplest:**

```
collection.push(newString);
collection.sort();
```

If you don't want duplicates, as in my use case:

```
if (!collection.includes(newString)) {
    collection.push(newString);
    collection.sort();
}
```

If you need to insert thousands of new strings at once in a loop, then just append them all to the original array first and call sort() at the end.

**Analysis of other (worse) solutions**

I originally benchmarked the proposed solutions as well as my own that I was going to propose as a "better" solution, but I realized that in real scenarios, nothing beats the simplicity of the push(), sort() method.

The test went like this:

1. generate a sorted array of 10,000 random 3-character all-caps strings
2. for each proposed solution, call it 10,000 times, inserting 10,000 new random strings of the same type into the sorted array
3. report how long it took to insert 10,000 additional strings

To make it a fair comparison, I made all methods reject duplicates.

In last place was Olian04's insertionSort method. If you think about it, the outer for-loop does nothing for the first `length-2` iterations and only once it gets to the final element that was just pushed does it actually insert that element where it goes.

Next up was Olian04's doubly-linked list method. It was only slightly faster than insertionSort at the expense of waaaaay more code complexity just to insert an element into an array. When I ran the test on 30,000 elements the doubly-linked list gave an `Error too much recursion`. Definitely only for use in comp sci classes and not real-world software.

The simple push, sort method I'm proposing as the best solution was around twice as fast as the doubly-linked list method.

My method (below) of just doing a linear scan of the original array to find the insertion index and insert using Array.prototype.splice() was moderately faster than push, sort.

The binarySearch proposed by OP and Victor was of course orders of magnitude faster, however it does not give correct output. (details below)

So why am I recommending what seems to be the third fasted solution? Because as I alluded to earlier, this is not representative of real usage. If you have thousands of elements to insert in rapid succession, you don't need to sort after each one. Just collect them all and sort once, which on my machine takes under 100ms.

For my use case, I am maintaining a sorted array of customer first names and another of last names to use for autocomplete suggestions by means of html datalists. So a new name is only inserted to the list when a human types in a name and clicks a button, which is exceedingly rare on the time scale of cpu cycles. Since it's just one insertion every now and then, I could use any of the proposed solutions and we won't be able to notice the difference. They all take milliseconds to do one insertion. So I'm going to go with the simpler code, using built-in functions.

The OP's intuition that a binary search is faster isn't bad, but I can't come up with a real scenario in which you need to run the algorithm thousands of time in rapid succession with each iteration having no knowledge of the previous iteration. That's the only hypothetical scenario in which the binary search is going to provide a noticeable benefit, provided you correct whatever is wrong with the code.

**My Original Solution (not recommending)**

For completeness, here's my linear search and splice method that beats push, sort in terms of rapid-fire speed, but not worth the extra code in practice:

```
function insertToSortedArray(collection, newString) {
  var insertionIndex = 0;
  while (collection[insertionIndex] < newString) {
        insertionIndex++;
  }
  if (collection[insertionIndex] == newString) return false; // remove this line to allow duplicates
  collection.splice(insertionIndex, 0, newString);
  return true;
}
```

I have it return true if it was inserted, false if it's a duplicate.

**Binary Search**

The proposed binarySearch function does not result in a sorted array. At least not according to the abc's my kindergarten taught me.

Just append the following code to Victor's code...

```
// *** Victor's code here ***

// create unsorted array of strings
const unsortedNames = [
    'MIGUEL',
    'LITXI',
    'YELMI',
    'CRISTY',
    'EVANGELINA',
    'MOISES',
    'ANYULI',
    'KARINA',
    'MAX',
    'EMANUEL',
    'GABRIELA',
    'ANTONIA',
    'ALEXIS',
    'JOEL',
    'LEONARDO',
    'VALERIA',
    'ERIKA',
    'MIGUEL',
    'YRENE',
    'ALMA',
    'AMALIA',
    'ANA',
    'ELI',
    'MAURICIO',
    'MIRIAM',
    'CAMILA',
    'ANDRE',
    'GERONIMO',
    'KARINA'
];

// use binarySearch to insert names into collection array one-by-one.

unsortedNames.forEach(name => {
    result= binarySearch(collection, name);
    // console.log(result)
    if(!result.found){
         // console.log('Adding '+item+' at index '+result.middle)
         collection.splice(result.middle, 0, name);
    }
});
console.log(collection);
```

The output is not correctly sorted. Even the first element is wrong along with many others. It seems to only be approximately sorted...

result:

```
[
    'ANTONIA',
    'ALEXIS',
    'ALMA',
    'AMALIA',
    'ABC',
    'ANA',
    'ANDRE',
    'ANYULI',
    'BCD',
    'CAMILA',
    'CAB',
    'EMANUEL',
    'CRISTY',
    'ELI',
    'EVANGELINA',
    'GERONIMO',
    'GABRIELA',
    'JOEL',
    'ERIKA',
    'CQW',
    'KARINA',
    'FGH',
    'KARINA',
    'LEONARDO',
    'LITXI',
    'MAX',
    'JKL',
    'MAURICIO',
    'MIGUEL',
    'MOISES',
    'VALERIA',
    'MIGUEL',
    'MIRIAM',
    'YELMI',
    'YRENE',
    'ZKL'
]
```

I'm sure it's not hard to fix, but if you're really interesting in getting O(log n) search/insert time, I suggest reading about binary search trees. They are made for this, and named for this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree